# codeigniter Automatic Logout issue

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

My site some times automatic logout so how can i stop this logout problem ?

This is the my config variable and codeigniter version is 2.2.0

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 0;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = false;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = true;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = true;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 7200;
```

Comment: Setting the "sess_expiration" to 0 will kill the session when the browser is closed. Set it to "172800" which is 48 hours.

Comment: When the session is set to 0 will expire straight away you should set it to 7200 which is 2 hours I think and what is the default when you get codeigniter 2.2.1

Answer (score 3):

You can go to config.php and set

```
$sess_expiration = 100000;//accroding to your requirment. (7200 is the default)
```

Comment: But codeigniter config mention that =>> 'sess_expiration'   = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.

Comment: yeah its set default of 2 hour and you can change it to your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to config.php and set

```
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 9000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I also face same issue auto logout. In config file set your sess_match_useragent value to false and test it, this work for me after three hour of digging on google.

```
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
```